# Can ImageMagick be packaged with python program? How to do it?

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I'm oscillating between opencv, Pillow, ImageMagick, subprocess and ffmpeg as a way to manipulate graphics data. ImageMagick looks good and quite powerful but already my installation on Win 7 doesn't run some of the commands because "no decode delegate for this image format" - an error caused by not installing it properly, not installing the most recent one or not installing various other dependencies it may have by some means that remain unclear even after reading around.

So with a, mostly, working version on my computer I'm wondering if its worth the time and trouble to create a graphics application in python using ImageMagick commands called using subprocess? If I make such an application can I include ImageMagick in it when I go to make a 1 file executable for distribution or sale? If so how can I do so? Do py2exe or pyinstaller enable you to include ImageMagick (and ffmpeg for that matter)?

Comment: Why not use the `Wand` Python module which gives you the ImageMagick functionality?

Comment: I thought that relied on ImageMagick anyway which needs to be installed and so would still require ImageMagick in the package/executable? Or are they separate? I also like the simplicity of ImageMagick commands from subprocess, not sure if the Wand module has all that functionality.

Comment: Try adding the `wand` tag and maybe Eric @emcconville will be able to clarify.

Comment: Python Wand now supports pretty much all the new features of ImageMagick. But its syntax is different from command line. Though the command names are very similar. It does need ImageMagick installed.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.

Ideally you would ship a Python package with a set-up script that would check the user's system for required dependencies, or at minimum, document how the end-user can install dependencies, where to find them, and why they should do such.

> If I make such an application can I include ImageMagick in it when I go to make a 1 file executable for distribution or sale?

Most of the dependencies are libraries (shared or static), so at minimum your "1 file executable" would need to link to additional files that you would distribute along side the Python code. This would also make you a distributor of mixed software licenses, and you would need to read & comply accordingly to each dependent library.

> Do py2exe or pyinstaller enable you to include ImageMagick (and ffmpeg for that matter)?

They'll include the corresponding DLL files for distribution, but not the delegates used by ImageMagick. I think there's a "portable" version of ImageMagick that is compiled with static libraries, and common delegates (including ffmpeg). Following [Providing the Microsoft Visual C runtime DLL](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step5) as an example. I would guess the set-up would look like:

```py
from glob import glob
data_files = [("ImageMagick.CRT", glob(r'C:\path\to\ImageMagick-7.0.8-67-portable-Q16-x86\*.*'))]
setup(
  data_files=data_files,
)
```

And use subprocess to call `magick.exe` in "ImageMagick.CRT" distributed directory.

> [...] I'm wondering if its worth the time and trouble to create a graphics application in python [...]

This all comes down to what your attempting to achieve. OpenCV & Pillow can be listed as dependencies in your applications `setup.py`, and the Python / Pip installer will handle it. However ImageMagick & FFMPEG are more of platforms (if not ecosystems) with their own level of customization & extensions.